# Typescript function to omit certain keys and add others from it's argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing a function whose job it is to take a raw api response and transform it into a shape that is more easily consumable in my app (let's call it a "pretty" response).

The code below is valid according to the TS compiler, but I want it to complain that I haven't removed the `metadata` key from the raw response before returning, as `metadata` exists in `RawResponse` but not in `PrettyResponse`.

I thought that my `Optionalize` type would do this for me, but it doesn't seem to be working.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Here's a [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?module=5&ts=3.7.5&ssl=18&ssc=76&pln=18&pc=87#code/PTAEHkFsEsBdQGYCcD2lQBVSwBYFNQBrPATwGdRoA7UAYzUhRoHc4dQBpAWAChYSADgXADY0JgEMANtABeeADxY8AD1h4qAEwocANJwB8oALwQYsJfuIkUCQwG5evauqQIJtAgCUJzL3jIBJjICAG9eUEjQTQlYCQAuUABtAF1HHijQSDw4mLjE8AAjACs8Wlh0gF8nHhc8Nw8CAAUkHP5-QOCwiKi8hOS0nsiAN3qycSpEslgkagBzKprgACpliOXMCWJQCVAkXx2BaD2AoKoQna1sffOEFCR0OEoqWBQd0AFW2H5QJjwAOnWoAAglIpHsDq1OucAqAcBJRjt4FI8BJpth8ERSBRbKAfH5Tl1-qB1sBeAgAK5UcoTD4SJAhDpnEJKUCqdRaCj4pldAwACihzLwiQwAEoCqIJtI5IoMPpuYSYUYAGSgFptEg8mGgcIZKL0c7wKEUqTwUxFUrlf5o8ZzKh80KVfSCrr6XWZTKjBkTRIAcgAjAAmADMvqGoEqovSmRAoAAyjgUCbNFRffAAJJwhEEV7RPAo9QnMgm2D-bK5WK7Qp4O6tE6wClIKjzAD84a%20jZoxtNix4NTqDU8oAAsprFRd3b1K4lUtGolQJNkpjN5nPIuWJH0CiUyhVeNU%20zwDeiXTDEqOtRdTJPIluBrpwwul6A0wFYGRfQ%209eucpvpzqDwPXhj3gSASHVb4x2hK86QZPBL0UC9xzwflTxCKNgOCFAUX%20KQUDmPkwIg9pkIwnggA) to illustrate as well.

```js
// Omit from T the keys in common with K
type Optionalize<T extends K, K> = Omit<T, keyof K>;

interface RawResponse {
    data: [];
    metadata: Object;
}

type PrettyResponse<T extends RawResponse> = Optionalize<T, RawResponse> & {
    data: [];
    version: string;
};

/**
 * Take a raw api response and transform it into a pretty one.
 * All raw responses have at least the keys of RawResponse. 
 */
function parseResponse<T extends RawResponse>(response: T): PrettyResponse<T> {
    const result = Object.assign({}, response, {
        version: '123'
    });
    // Shouldn't I have to delete result.metadata before returning?
    return result;
}
```

And an example of consuming it:

```js
interface MyResponse {
    data: [];
    name: string;
    category: string;
    other?: number;
    metadata: Object;
}

const response: MyResponse = {
    data: [],
    name: 'a',
    category: 'blah',
    metadata: {}
}

const myPrettyResponse: PrettyResponse<MyResponse> = parseResponse<MyResponse>(response);
```

*Note: My colleague pointed out that this may be due to Typescript's use of [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), but I would still expect the explicit return definition of `Optionalize<T, RawResponse>` to remove the `metadata` key.*

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to add `metadata: never` to `MyResponse`, then it will always complain to delete it (set to undefined).

```js
interface RawResponse {
    data: [];
    metadata: Object;
}

type BannedKeys = 'metadata';

type PrettyResponse<T> = Omit<T, BannedKeys> & Record<BannedKeys, never> & {
    version: string;
}

function parseResponse<T extends RawResponse>(response: T): PrettyResponse<T> {
    const updatedResponse: PrettyResponse<T> = {
        ...response,
        version: '123',
        metadata: undefined, // if you comment it - it will ask to delete it.
    }

    return updatedResponse;
}

interface MyResponse {
    data: [];
    name: string;
    category: string;
    other?: number;
    metadata: Object;
}

const response: MyResponse = {
    data: [],
    name: 'a',
    category: 'blah',
    metadata: {}
}

const myPrettyResponse: PrettyResponse<MyResponse> = parseResponse<MyResponse>(response);

myPrettyResponse.metadata // is undefined.
```

Comment: While that would work, it's not scalable as it requires the caller to stay up to date with the superfluous properties in the `RawResponse` that they don't care about.

Comment: Do you want to get all properties from `RawResponse` and exclude banned one only? is it correct?

Comment: Could you give me an option? from the question it sounds like you want to ban `metadata`, that's implemented above.